# Quote "I am Gandalf, and Gandalf means me!" (The Hobbit)

Tags: meaning-in-context

what does the word **"mean"** mean in the quote "I am Gandalf, and Gandalf means me!". It should have been **"is"** instead, right?

- "I am Gandalf, and Gandalf **is** me!"

Comment: When you say Gandalf, you *mean* him, not someone else.

Comment: So here "Gandalf" is a word in the second part, not a name.

Comment: It is his name, and obviously, it's also a word.

Comment: Note the sentence is preceded by: "And you do know my name, though you don't remember that I belong to it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an idiomatic usage of ***[mean](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mean)*** to give emphasis to what you want to express:

> - [ T ] used to add emphasis to what you are saying:
>
>   - *I want you home by midnight. And I mean midnight.*

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: Can I say something like this then, "When I say you, I mean You!" will it have sense?

Comment: Yes, you are underlining  the fact that you really mean "you".

Comment: Tolkien's turn of phrase might also imply that there is **only one** Gandalf in all of Middle-Earth, and it is he.